# How to change Excel Column Type in JS Script to Text before Exporting Data into Excel Sheet?

Tags: javascript, excel

I am needing to convert 5 columns to TEXT before the program writes the data to it because Excel changes my 8 digit formatted date (MM/DD/YY) that gets outputted to those columns to the Date format (MM/DD/YYYY). The outputted date needs to stay in the 8 digit format in order to rerun it as the next input file to update the system. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have tried using:

```
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").TextToColumns;
```

but it did not work. Here's all of the code:

```js
<script> 
function js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss () {    
now = new Date();    
year = "" + now.getFullYear();    
month = "" + (now.getMonth() + 1);    
if (month.length == 1)    {       month = "0" + month;     }    
day = "" + now.getDate();    
if (day.length == 1)    {       day = "0" + day;     }    
hour = "" + now.getHours();    
if (hour.length == 1)    {       hour = "0" + hour;     }    
minute = "" + now.getMinutes();    
if (minute.length == 1)    {       minute = "0" + minute;     }    
second = "" + now.getSeconds();    
if (second.length == 1)    {       second = "0" + second;     }    
return month + "" + day + "" + year.substring(2) + "" + hour + "" + minute + "" + second;  } 

function pad(num, len) {    var str = '' + num;    while (str.length < len)    {       str = '0' + str;     }    return str;  } function writeToExcel() {    try    {       var loanStr;       var FullRecs;       var passFail;       var Processed = 0;       var Rejected = 0;       var D9ID;       var time;       var date;       var datetime;       var row = 0;       var col;       var str = document.getElementById("outstr").value;       var headerStr = "|Account|Stop_Code_1|SC_1_Date|Stop_Code_2|SC_2_Date|Stop_Code_3|SC_3_Date|Lockout_Code|Lock_Date|Warning_Code|Warning_Date|";       var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");       var excelBook = ExcelSheet.Workbooks.Add;       var RSheet = excelBook.Worksheets(1);       ExcelSheet.Worksheets.Activate;       ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Name = "Removals-" + js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss ();       var outputdate = month + "-" + day + "-" + year.substring(2);       var outputtime = hour + "-" + minute;       var writefilepath = document.getElementById("writepath").value;       var filepath = writefilepath.substring(0, writefilepath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1); filepath = filepath + "DEL LOAN CODE Removal" + "_" + outputdate + "_" + outputtime + "_" + "OUTPUT" + ".xlsx"; date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year.substring(2); time = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second; RSheet.Cells(1, 3).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 4).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 5).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 6).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 7).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 8).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 9).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 10).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 11).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 12).ColumnWidth = 15; RSheet.Cells(1, 13).ColumnWidth = 15; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).value = ""; var headings = headerStr.split("|"); for(var k = 0; k < (headings.length - 1); k ++ ) {    ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(7, k + 2).value = headings[k];  } FullRecs = str.split("~~"); for(var m = 0; m < (FullRecs.length - 1); m = m + 2) {    loanStr = FullRecs[m].split("^");    for(var i = 0; i < (loanStr.length - 1); i ++ )    {       var fieldStr = loanStr[i].split("|");       for(var j = 0; j < (fieldStr.length); j ++ )       {          ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(row + 8, j + 2).value = fieldStr[j];        }       row = row + 1;     } } for(var n = 1; n <= (FullRecs.length - 1); n = n + 2) {    passFail = FullRecs[n].split("|");    D9ID = passFail[0];    Processed = Processed + Number(passFail[1]);    Rejected = Rejected + Number(passFail[2]);  } var total = Number(Processed) + Number(Rejected) ; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).value = "USER"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).value = "SUMMARY"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).value = "DATE"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).value = date; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).value = "TIME"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 3).value = time; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).value =  D9ID; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4).value = "PROCESSED ITEMS"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 5).value = + Processed; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).value = "REJECTED ITEMS"; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 5).value = + Rejected; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("B2, B3, B4, D2, D3, D4, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,M7").Font.Bold = true; for( var rb = 2; rb < 5; rb ++ ) {    for( var cb = 2; cb < 6; cb ++ )    {       RSheet.Cells(rb, cb).BorderAround(1).LineStyle = 1;     } } for( var datarow = 7; datarow <= (7 + Number(total)); datarow ++ ) {    for( var datacolumn = 3; datacolumn < 14; datacolumn ++ )    {       RSheet.Cells(datarow, datacolumn).BorderAround(1).LineStyle = 1;     } } ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:P").HorizontalAlignment = 2; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("C2", "C4").HorizontalAlignment = 3; ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("E2", "E4").HorizontalAlignment = 3; excelBook.SaveAs(filepath); ExcelSheet.Visible = false; ExcelSheet.UserControl = true; ExcelSheet.Application.Quit(); return true;  } catch(e) { if(e.number == - 2146827284) {    alert(e.description + ". Please close the document.");    ExcelSheet.Application.Quit();    ExcelSheet.Quit();    ExcelSheet = null;    return false;  } } } </script>
```

Comment: Set the number format of the date cells to "mm/dd/yy"  before you populate the dates.  That will not affect the underlying cell value though: how that affects your next input is unclear.

Comment: How would I do that within the code chunk above?

Comment: I can't really say, since you code is not correctly formatted and so more or less unreadable?  Try recording a macro in excel while applying the format and use that as the basis for your fix.

Comment: The code is within a client API program that creates the excel doc and writes the data to it. I am unable to use a Macro.

Comment: "as the basis for your fix" means use the syntax from the VBA to adapt your code to add the required formatting.  It's not so different.